# Can anyone identify this component? Looks like an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to identify IC3 in this picture.

IC2 is a LM723 and this is (obviously) a power supply. IC3 looks like an op-amp but I don't recognize some extra pins there: VC and FC.

Does anyone have a guess?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: MIght be a specialty amp, which basically tells you nothing since those are all different. I don't know why the author would omit the IC part number on the rectangular ICs but none of the other components. Presumably, those were symbols they made and they did it sloppily.

Comment: @DKNguyen, they're LM723 voltage regulators or equivalent. U3 is being used as a comparator.

Comment: VC is the collector voltage pin and FC is the pin for connect filter condenser for internal voltage regulator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like IC2 and IC3 are both voltage regulator chips of type [NTE923](https://www.tme.eu/Document/6175f705093194863710b50a550503ff/nte923.pdf): -

[image]

Looks like they are equivalent to the [LM723](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm723.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe): -

[image]

Comment: They are both LM723, stop on! I guess that is it. Transistor commented above that it is being used as comparator, and I think that too, I really didn’t realize they were the same because some pins are hidden. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me that they are using a second LM723 as a comparator. The output in this chip is more like a voltage follower rather than the open-collector output favoured in typical comparators.

[image]

*Figure 1. LM723 pinout. Original pin numbering is for the metal can variant. The yellow circled numbers are for the 14-pin DIL and match your schematic.*

Answer (score 2):

IC2 is working like a voltage regulator. IC3 is comparing  the current sense resistor voltage to the control current setting, if the current is more that the setting. It will shut down IC2 , turn off voltage control led and turn on current control led.

Answer (score 1):

This is series voltage regulator, LM723.  I've used these for building DC Variable Voltage Regulator Power supplies for about 45 years

Comment: It may be an LM723 but U3's application is not obvious as it is being used as a comparator, not as a linear regulator. Read the other answers. Welcom to EE.SE.